# Create and send excel sheet as an email attachment in php

Tags: php, excel

I am generating an excel sheet filtering the database and after completing this step, I have to send an email to particular user attaching this excel sheet. I was able to create and download the excel file however I am not able to send it as an attachment.

What am I missing in this code?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $link = mysqli_connect("Host", "Username", "Password", "database");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }
  else{
    $yesterday = date('d-m-Y',strtotime("-1 days")); //Get yesterday's date
    $file="E-Call_List - ".$yesterday.".xls"; 
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT a.psemobile, b.activity, a.memid1, b.LoginTime, b.LogoutTime FROM tblMembers a, tblMonitor b WHERE a.memid1 = b.memberid AND b.date ='".$yesterday."'";
    $result = $link->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              $test ="<table border=1>
                    <tr>
                      <th>DATE</th>
                      <th>MEMBER ID</th>
                      <th>LOGIN TIME</th>
                      <th>LOGOUT TIME</th>
                      <th>MOBILE</th>
                      <th>ACTIVITY</th>
                    </tr>";
          echo $test;
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
          {
            echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>".$yesterday."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row["memid1"]."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row["LoginTime"]."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row["LogoutTime"]."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row["psemobile"]."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row["activity"]."</td>";
            echo "<tr>";
          }
          $to = 'rec@outlook.com';
          $subject = 'Test email Partner Solution';
          $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
          $headers = "From: Sender@gmail.com\r\nReply-To: Sender@gmail.com";
          $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed;";
          $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
          $message = "<b>Greetings.</b>";
          $message .= "<b>This is a test email.</b>";
          $message = ob_get_clean();
          $mail_sent = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    }
    else {
      echo "0 results";
    }
    $link->close();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what could be the possibilities?

Comment: Try to specify Content-Length for the e-mail

Comment: $headers .= "\r\nContent-Length: 3000"; gave me no change.

Comment: is 3000 correct?

Comment: Any digits greater than 0 will work correct?

Comment: try it with the correct length of that email in bytes.

Comment: I don't want to save excel sheet into my server directory. I just want to create this file and send it.

Comment: Okay, I will try that.Other than that, do you see any issues with my code?

Comment: like that problem that `$attachement` is unused in your whole code? :) See this question for more information about how to send an attachement via php-mail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail

Comment: Php mailer takes a path of a file, In my case I don't want to save or download excel file. I just want to create it with some name and then send it. Is it possible?

Comment: read more than only one line of that link

Comment: I figured it out but forgot to inform. Thanks guys!.